# Neither of the statistical functions appear to work in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

When I attempt to run following query on a double column:

```
SELECT stddev_samp(col1) FROM t1
```

I get:

```
Error: SELECT: no such unary operator 'stddev_samp(double)'
SQLState:  22000
ErrorCode: 0
```

If I run it against an int column, I get:

```
Error: SELECT: no such unary operator 'stddev_samp(int)'
SQLState:  22000
ErrorCode: 0
```

And I am getting the same type of error when I attempt to execute any of the stat_func mentioned at: https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/StatisticFunctions

It looks like if I didn't install support for statistic functions because otherwise MonetDB works well. Is there a procedure how to add statistic functions?

Background knowledge:

1. Version: MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v1.1 (Oct2014-SP2)
2. OS: OS X 10.9.5
3. The database was installed from archive: MonetDB-11.19.9-x86_64-Darwin-9-bin.tar.bz2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Option 1) try using

```
SYS.STDDEV_SAMPLE ()
SYS.MEDIAN ()
```

etc... instead of "plain"

```
STDDEV_SAMPLE ()
MEDIAN ()
```

Option 2) (not recommended):

Work with the user named `monetdb`.

Comment: The trick with "sys." prefix worked.

Out of curiosity I also tried to use "monetdb" user, but the statistical functions still require "sys." prefix. 

Since I can live the prefix, your post answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this code works fine.  it will be difficult to help you troubleshoot until you provide a [complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).    :)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( col1 INT, col2 DOUBLE ); 
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ( 1 , 3 ) , ( 2.0 , 4.0 ) ;
SELECT stddev_samp( col1 ) FROM t1 ;
SELECT stddev_samp( col2 ) FROM t1 ;
SELECT stddev_pop( col1 ) FROM t1 ;
SELECT stddev_pop( col2 ) FROM t1 ;
```

Comment: Btw. Downgrading to MonetDB-11.19.7-x86_64-Darwin-9-bin.tar.bz2  solves the issue - all four selects then return the expected values.

Comment: could you submit this to bugs.monetdb.org?  thanks  :)

Comment: nice.  the monetdb folks are pretty excellent about fixing issues once they're properly narrowed down like this.  thank you!